# Installing Ghost 1.8.6 with sqlite db fails after configuring systemd

Tags: sqlite, installation, raspberry-pi3, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm trying to install a hosted version of Ghost following the installation guide at https://docs.ghost.org/v1/docs/install. With the exception that in my case I want to use sqlite3 as database.

However every step went successfully but after prompting for configure systemd it crash with the following error message:

```
Message: 'Command failed: /bin/sh -c sudo -E -u ghost /usr/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/node_modules/.b
in/knex-migrator-migrate --init --mgpath /var/www/ghost/current
```

Here is the output for the logs:

```
Debug Information:
   Node Version: v6.11.3
   Ghost-CLI Version: 1.1.1
   Environment: production
   Command: 'ghost install --db sqlite3 --dbpath ./content/data/ghost.db'
An error occurred.
Message: 'Command failed: /bin/sh -c sudo -E -u ghost /usr/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/node_modules/.b
in/knex-migrator-migrate --init --mgpath /var/www/ghost/current
'Stack: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c sudo -E -u ghost /usr/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/node_module
s/.bin/knex-migrator-migrate --init --mgpath /var/www/ghost/current    at Promise.all.then.arr (/usr/lib/node_modules/ghost-cli/node_modules/execa/index.js:236:11)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Code: 1
```

The underlying hardware is a Raspberry PI 3 with Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was the sqlite3 package.

The ghost installer try to install sqlite3 via node but it seems there is no binaries for all the platforms which makes sqlite3 try to compile from sources.
And it was there when it fails. After uninstalling ghost via `ghost uninstall` and then installing sqlite3 separate via `npm install -g sqlite3` which also try to compile from sources it worked. (First time it failed anyway but i could not know if it was some network issue, i just run the command again and if worked).
After that I installed Ghost again and it seems to take the compiled version saved globally.